# Cant get map to display?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

I am trying to add google maps to my web app, but all I am getting right now is just a blank page. No, errors, just a blank page.

I am using mrt:googlemaps package to use googlemaps.

This is my google maps page:

```
<template name="customerhome">  
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px;height:500px;margin:10px auto"></div>
</template>
```

And this my app.js page:

```
UserAccounts = new Mongo.Collection('users'); 

GoogleMaps.init(
    {
        'sensor': true, //optional
        'key': 'MY-GOOGLEMAPS-API-KEY', //optional
        'language': 'de' //optional
    }, 
    function(){
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions); 
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng( 35.363556, 138.730438 ));
    }
);
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: wrap it into a Meteor.isClient, I think since it's trying to run it on both client and server it's breaking

Comment: fwiw here's a meteorpad: meteorpad.com/pad/X2CsxkZ2LgmCrkT2H/Maps  .   I can see the map render for a few seconds before the API key warning appears.   I would recommend to put the map init inside an onRendered, I'm surprised it works outside onRendered.

Comment: never mind it worked, just had to remove the new mongo.collection in app.js